# getting sql error while deleting data from dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

team,

My sql query is like below i am using sql server 2014.Here @abcTableName some time may exist and some time may not. so we getting that table by querying available tables in a database

```
 DECLARE @dat datetime, @abcTableName varchar(127);
 set  @m_lCleanUpAfterDays=30;
 set @dat = getdate() - @m_lCleanUpAfterDays;   
 SET @tabledelete = 'DELETE TOP(1)  FROM ' + @abcTableName+ ' WHERE EventTime < ' + @your_dt ;
 EXEC(@dynDelete);
```

here **EventTime  datatype is datetime** only, but still i am getting **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string** exception. i have tried conversion for @dat also, but still i am getting the same exception. Please help me ,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
 SET @tabledelete = 'DELETE TOP(1)  FROM ' + @abcTableName+ ' WHERE EventTime < ' + @your_dt;
```

Presumably `@your_dt` is a date time? If it is, you are going to have to cast it to an NVARCHAR to be able to build the string, e.g.

```
 SET @tabledelete = 'DELETE TOP(1)  FROM ' + @abcTableName+ ' WHERE EventTime < ' + ''''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @your_dt, 103) +'''' ;
```

Chose the format you require: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: But here time is formatting. i want to use both date time

Comment: @Andrues Edited my answer with a link to date formats. You can choose the correct format.

Comment: i ve tried with CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), @your_dt, 201), but its giving Incorrect syntax near '10' error. Here 10 is hours.at the start og time its giving error.

Comment: @Andrues when ever you are building strings PRINT is handy to see what is going on. You are not containing your date in inverted commas - Ensure it is enclosed in them.

Comment: here i am getting datetime like this 2017-07-12 10:24:47.997,is  i need to close with '2017-07-12 10:24:47.997' like this?

Comment: @Andrues - yes.